# Android studio => Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android

So I want to create an android app that displays music and when I click on an item in the recyclerview it keeps crashing and showing the logcat error: Attempt to get length of null array even though I know that the list is not null.

Here is my code:

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MusicAdapter musicAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> musicList;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        musicList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("removed_songs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(musicList, this, sharedPreferences);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        } else {
            getMusic();
        }

        Button refreshButton = findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply();
                getMusic();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getMusic();
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    private void getMusic() {
        musicList.clear();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);
        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            do {
                String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                String removedSong = sharedPreferences.getString(currentTitle, null);
                if (removedSong == null) {
                    musicList.add(currentTitle);
                }
            } while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        songCursor.close();
        musicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}




MusicAdapter.java

public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder> {
    private List<String> musicList;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public MusicAdapter(ArrayList<String> musicList, Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        this.musicList = musicList;
        this.context = context;
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.music_item, parent, false);
        return new MusicViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MusicViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        final String songName = musicList.get(position);
        holder.songNameTextView.setText(songName);
        holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Jeste li sigurni da želite maknuti pjesmu iz liste?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Da", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        musicList.remove(songName);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(songName, songName);
                        editor.apply();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Ne", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SongPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("song_name", songName);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return musicList.size();
    }

    public class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView songNameTextView;
        ImageButton removeButton;

        public MusicViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMusic);
            songNameTextView.setSelected(true);
            //OVO SVE JE POTREBNO ZA ANIMACIJU PREDUGOG TEKSTA (UKLJUCUJUCI: songNameTextView.setSelected(true))
            //        android:ellipsize="marquee"
            //        android:singleLine="true"
            //        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            //        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            removeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
        }
    }
}





Song.java

    public class Song implements Serializable {
        String path;
        String title;
        String duration;

        public Song(String path, String title, String duration) {
            this.path = path;
            this.title = title;
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public void setDuration(String duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }
    }


And also SongPlayerActivity.java

public class SongPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ArrayList<String> songList;
    private int currentSongIndex;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private ImageButton playBtn, nextBtn, prevBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_player);

        // get the song list from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        songList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("musicList");
        currentSongIndex = intent.getIntExtra("songIndex", 0);
        String currentSongPath = songList.get(currentSongIndex);

        // initialize the MediaPlayer
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        // initialize the UI elements
        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.pause_play);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.next);
        prevBtn = findViewById(R.id.previous);

        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    pauseSong();
                } else {
                    playSong();
                }
            }
        });

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playNextSong();
            }
        });

        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playPrevSong();
            }
        });

        // play the current song
        playSong();
    }

    private void playSong() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            String currentSongPath = songList.get(currentSongIndex);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentSongPath);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void pauseSong() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
        playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    private void playNextSong() {
        if (currentSongIndex < songList.size() - 1) {
            currentSongIndex++;
            playSong();
        }
    }

    private void playPrevSong() {
        if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
            currentSongIndex--;
            playSong();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        playNextSong();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

I honestly don't know what is wrong I keep getting the same error and I think there is something wrong either in the SongPlayerActivity or something with the intent in MusicAdapter.

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the error. thanks

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                     at com.example.myapplication.SongPlayerActivity.onCreate(SongPlayerActivity.java:32)

Comment: is the answer below helping to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the `MusicAdapter` class, update the `setOnClickListener` callback in the following way:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SongPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("musicList", musicList);
                intent.putExtra("song_name", songName);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

then declare `musicList` variable as `ArrayList<String>` instead of `List<String>`